# Logitech k400r wireless keyboard trackpad settings for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, keyboard, trackpad, logitech, logitech-unifying

I brought a [Logitech Wireless Touch Keyboard K400r](http://www.logitech.com/en-in/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r) and plugged it to my laptop, OS is Ubuntu 14.04. It worked just out of the box. However the problem I noticed that its trackpad is very slow and I wanted to change its settings. [Setpoint](http://www.logitech.com/en-in/mice-pointers/articles/11650) software which Logitech provides to customize keyboard option doesn't have a linux distribution. The only option which I find for Ubuntu was [Solaar app](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/logitech-unifying-receiver-linux-solaar). Though it has some options, but do not include trackpad settings. Is there any workaround of trackpad settings available for this Logitech wireless keyboard running on Ubuntu? Basically I am looking for Logitech Setpoint alternative in Ubuntu.

Update --

After searching a lot, I found [hidpoint](http://www.hidpoint.com/) which seems to be not active anymore.

Comment: Solaar is the unofficial SetPoint alternative for Linux, can't you control cursor speed through the normal mouse settings?

Comment: The default keyboard settings is only controlling laptop's inbuilt keyboard. No option to control Logitech's wireless one.  I understand that Solaar is not official. I tried searching something related to Logitech alternative software for wireless mouse keyboard. But no luck. For windows Logitech provides a software Setpoint to control such thing. Bad part is that Logitech do not provide Setpoint's linux verion

Comment: The trackpad is treated as mouse device, so you should look at the pointer settings, not the keyboard one. The hardware reports very fine changes, but software (probably libinput / xf86-input-evdev) should interpret it. The pointer settings should allow you to control those properties and is exposed via a standard API, but the graphical user interface to control it varies between desktop environments.

Answer (score 1):

Forget Solaar, you can do it natively (I'm on Xubuntu Core 18.04, but this apparently [worked on Ubuntu 9.10 already](https://patrickmn.com/aside/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10)). I have a Logitech K400 Pro which I transformed from a piece of junk into a working piece of junk w/

```
$ xinput
```

take note of the id of the *pointer*, not keyboard of your K400. Suppose it's 10, then

```
$ xinput --list-props 10
```

note interesting lines:

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Accel Speed (289): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (290): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (291):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (292):   1, 0
```

increase sensitivity:

```
$ xinput --set-prop 10 289 1
$ xinput --set-prop 10 292 0 0
$ xinput --set-prop 10 145 2 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to this page as I was trying to find a way to keep function keys as normal (and not their K400/r special functions which works in windows). Finally found it in Solaar, which has a "Swap Fx function" which should be turned to OFF

[image]

Comment: I tried Solaar on 20.04, but it does not show my K400r device.