# Solaar not correctly working for Logitech K400r keyboard in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard, logitech

I have upgraded my hardware and my ubuntu version and have installed ubuntu 16.04. In Ubuntu 14.04 my Logitech keyboard worked fine and was recognised as K401r keyboard.
In Ubuntu 16.04 the keyboard is working but I need to use it closer to the receiver and that's not convenient when I want to sit on my couch (this is my media pc for my living room). Does anyone know how to make it a K401r keyboard again or is that not a solution?

My Logitech Mouse M235 is also not working well and is not moving smooth over the desktop.

I have tried this [Logitech k400r wireless keyboard trackpad settings for Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608298/logitech-k400r-wireless-keyboard-trackpad-settings-for-ubuntu-14-04) but to no avail.

Any suggestions anyone?

Bas Douma

Comment: Have you tried putting new AA batteries in the keyboard?

Comment: Is your Logitech Unifying dongle plugged directly into a computer USB port? It shouldn't be behind any USB hub or extender.

Comment: Both new batteries and plugging the receiver directly into a USB port makes no difference, sadly. Is there a way to set solaar to recognise it as a k401r keyboard?

Comment: I read that the settings are in a file called ~/.config/solaar/config.json . I tried to look  for that same file in my backup of ubuntu 14.04 but the file is not in that location.

Comment: After I plugged in the receievers on the front ports and reinstalling ubuntu 16 and solaar and it seems to work fine although solaar does not recognise my keyboard anymore only the mouse.